# IStream write perfomance issues on Windows 8.1

Tags: c#, performance, istream

I'm working on .NET C# app that implements virtual files drag and drop from app to Windows Explorer. I got implementation idea and sample code from [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/delay/archive/2009/11/04/creating-something-from-nothing-asynchronously-developer-friendly-virtual-file-implementation-for-net-improved.aspx). After file drop the app downloads a file and writes it to IStream wrapper. That works fine on Windows 7 x64, but that works very slow for files about 30 MB and larger and takes a lot of CPU resources and Memory on Windows 8.1.
Any ideas will be appreciated. Thanks in advance. The code is:

1) IStreamWrapper class

```
        private class IStreamWrapper : Stream
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// IStream instance being wrapped.
        /// </summary>
        private IStream _iStream;

        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes a new instance of the IStreamWrapper class.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="iStream">IStream instance to wrap.</param>
        public IStreamWrapper(IStream iStream)
        {
            _iStream = iStream;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets a value indicating whether the current stream supports reading.
        /// </summary>
        public override bool CanRead
        {
            get { return false; }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets a value indicating whether the current stream supports seeking.
        /// </summary>
        public override bool CanSeek
        {
            get { return false; }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets a value indicating whether the current stream supports writing.
        /// </summary>
        public override bool CanWrite
        {
            get { return true; }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Clears all buffers for this stream and causes any buffered data to be written to the underlying device.
        /// </summary>
        public override void Flush()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the length in bytes of the stream.
        /// </summary>
        public override long Length
        {
            get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the position within the current stream.
        /// </summary>
        public override long Position
        {
            get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
            set { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Reads a sequence of bytes from the current stream and advances the position within the stream by the number of bytes read.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="buffer">An array of bytes. When this method returns, the buffer contains the specified byte array with the values between offset and (offset + count - 1) replaced by the bytes read from the current source.</param>
        /// <param name="offset">The zero-based byte offset in buffer at which to begin storing the data read from the current stream.</param>
        /// <param name="count">The maximum number of bytes to be read from the current stream.</param>
        /// <returns>The total number of bytes read into the buffer. This can be less than the number of bytes requested if that many bytes are not currently available, or zero (0) if the end of the stream has been reached.</returns>
        public override int Read(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Sets the position within the current stream.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="offset">A byte offset relative to the origin parameter.</param>
        /// <param name="origin">A value of type SeekOrigin indicating the reference point used to obtain the new position.</param>
        /// <returns>The new position within the current stream.</returns>
        public override long Seek(long offset, SeekOrigin origin)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Sets the length of the current stream.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="value">The desired length of the current stream in bytes.</param>
        public override void SetLength(long value)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Writes a sequence of bytes to the current stream and advances the current position within this stream by the number of bytes written.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="buffer">An array of bytes. This method copies count bytes from buffer to the current stream.</param>
        /// <param name="offset">The zero-based byte offset in buffer at which to begin copying bytes to the current stream.</param>
        /// <param name="count">The number of bytes to be written to the current stream.</param>
        public override void Write(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
        {
            if (offset == 0)
            {
                // Optimize common case to avoid creating extra buffers
                _iStream.Write(buffer, count, IntPtr.Zero);
            }
            else
            {
                // Easy way to provide the relevant byte[]
                _iStream.Write(buffer.Skip(offset).ToArray(), count, IntPtr.Zero);
            }
        }
    }
```

2) Creating IStream and writing to it:

```
    public void SetData(short dataFormat, int index, Action<Stream> streamData)
    {
        ...           
        var iStream = NativeMethods.CreateStreamOnHGlobal(IntPtr.Zero, true);

        if (streamData != null)
        {
           // Wrap in a .NET-friendly Stream and call provided code to fill it
           using(var stream = new IStreamWrapper(iStream))
           {
               streamData(stream); // calls downloadFile(stream);
           }
        }
        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(iStream);
        ...
     }

     // that will be called by streamData(stream)
     private void downloadFile(Stream wStream) {
     ...
                HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
                if (response.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
                {
                    throw new WebException(String.Format("Server error (HTTP {0}: {1}).", response.StatusCode, response.StatusDescription));
                }
                using (Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream())
                {
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
                    while ((bytesRead = stream.Read(buffer, 0, 4096)) != 0)
                    {
                        wStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                    }
                }         
     ...
    }
```

Comment: Perhaps this type of question is better suited for CodeReview.StackExchange.

Comment: Look in the Output window for a large number of "First chance exception" notifications.  Debug with Debug + Exceptions, Thrown checkbox for CLR exceptions.